# Concatenating multiple hyperlinks in one cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, concatenation

Now that it is possible to have multiple links within the same Google Sheets cell, I'm trying to automate some grunt work with a Mail Merge add-on. The add-on takes multiple "attachments" that are hyperlinks separated by commas and does a great job of mailing them out if I copy and paste the links in manually.

I'm using this to build individual unique emails of tests for my students so I can type in the sheets Questions A, B and Q for student 1, Questions B, C and Q for student 2. I use VLOOKUP to grab the links from a separate page that replaces Question A with the hyperlink for Question A, etc. Then I used CONCATENTATE with commas and spaces between links to build the cell that has the 3 "attachments" in it.
But it only sees the text and doesn't turn it into an active hyperlink.

If I make a copy of that CONCATENATEd text and paste as value, then go in and press the space bar after the commas, the links turn blue or "live", and then it works.

I would love to automate this. Any suggestions?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score -1):

I'd be interested in automating this as well but it seems unavailable at the moment. One possible workaround (albeit a less elegant one) is to use the plain URL itself (instead of hiding it in a hyperlinked text) and separate the concatenated links by a comma or a carriage return. Gmail tends to auto-convert plain URLs into hyperlinked text. You could try a test email to yourself via the above method to ensure the concatenated URLs are converted to clickable links.